# How to rank the date in Excel without duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good Morning.

I have a question about ranking date in excel, please see the image below, in the rank column,

I used formula:

```
=RANK($A3,$A:$A,1)
```

but this is not what i want.

I just want the same date share same ranking as it is shown in my Target Format column. Can anyone please tell me know what formula should I apply to achieve this goal.

Much Appreciate.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can try an array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$1:A$6<A1)/COUNTIF(A$1:A$6,A$1:A$6&""))+1
```

Assuming date in in Column A.

Here's a good discussion on this formula: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/672016-un-skipping-the-rank-after-a-duplicate-value-to-get-a-regular-series.html

my output:

```
Date        number  rank
8/15/2017   1234    1
8/15/2017   4321    1
8/15/2017   4325    1
8/17/2017   8970    2
8/17/2017   8971    2
8/20/2017   5674    3
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will look at the link you share.

Comment: @Vico Is there a way to repeat this process for each set of ID's or cases (each case has several dates that are to be rank ordered)?

Answer (score 2):

Try to enter this and press `Shift + Ctrl + Enter` altogether:

`=SUM(IF(A3>$A$3:$A$8,1/COUNTIF($A$3:$A$8,$A$3:$A$8)))+1`

Then drag down the formula to see the results.

Or second way (Doesn't need Shift + Ctrl + Enter):

`=SUMPRODUCT((A3>A$3:A$8)/COUNTIF(A$3:A$8,A$3:A$8))+1`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty answer that requires a helper column. For the first row, manually enter `1`. For the following rows, check if the rank has changed. If the rank is the same as previous, use the previous modified rank. Otherwise, increment the previous modified rank: `=IF(B3=B2,C2,C2+1)`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tiebreak column

[image]

The FinalRank is just the sum of Rank and TieBreak.

Copied from http://www.contextures.com/excel-functions-rank.html#ties

Answer (score 1):

If you sort your data by date all you need to do is write number 1 in `C2` and use formula from `C3` till end:

```
=IF(A3=A2,C2,C2+1)
```