# INDEX/MATCH formula only shows one result instead of all

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables, and two matching criterias (in Column A and B) in both of them. I also have multiple identical entries in these two criterias. My formula only shows the first of them, but I need to get all results shown in the table2  in column C and D

Data from Column F and G in table1 should be shown in column C and D, but not only one, but all of them.

In [image: table1] you can see two entries with the same criteria in A and B, but only one of it shows up in [image: table2] with my formula.

What do I have to do to get all results shown up in table2?

Formula in column C is:
`=INDEX(Abos2019!$F$2:$F$1770;VERGLEICH(A2&B2;Abos2019!$A$1:$A$1770&Abos2019!$B$1:$B$1770;0))`

Formula in column D is:
`=INDEX(Abos2019!$G$2:$G$1770;VERGLEICH(A2&B2;Abos2019!$A$1:$A$1770&Abos2019!$B$1:$B$1770;0))`

Comment: You will only get one match, as that is what you ask for. I suggest using a pivot table in your case.

Comment: You need to  check out things like ranking or top 5 without duplicates, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/45841723/4961700 as an example. I did this for tracking students absences ie top 5 students when some have same absence score...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this, it brings back the name based on the highest absences:

[image]

Note, I only want the Top 5, so you may want to change that...

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I need in the end. I only need the data from table1 in column F and G showing up in table2 in column C and D if the criteria in A and B matches. But not only the first hit, but all of them. Any ideas how I can arrange this by modifying the formulas I already use?

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: I didn't get it. And I'm not sure if we talk about the same result in the end. I don't need to get a list. I only want the data from table1 'Abos2019' in columns F and G to be shown in table2 'Empfaengerdaten' in columns C and D if the data in columns A and B in both tables shows exactly the same numbers. My formula only gives out the first hit, but I need all hits show up row by row.