# Rank ordering dates (and repeating the command for each ID/person)

Tags: excel, repeat, ranking

I have a series of dates for each case (person) in a dataset. I am trying to rank order these dates (with duplicates) for each person.

My question is a direct application of this thread:

[How to rank the date in Excel without duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841723/how-to-rank-the-date-in-excel-without-duplicates)

And I would simply like to figure out how to repeat this for over 100 cases I have in the dataset.

Example codes I have from the above thread:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$1:A$6<A1)/COUNTIF(A$1:A$6,A$1:A$6&""))+1
```

Now, I can I have excel repeat this code separately for each person (distinguished by ID).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the other criteria:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$13=A2)*($B$2:$B$13<B2))/(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$13,$B$2:$B$13,$A$2:$A$13,A2)+($A$2:$A$13<>A2)))+1
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly on a subset of samples but I have yet to have the final output with over 16000 rows (status says it is calculating with 4 processors at 0% for a good while). Any way to make this go faster?

Comment: Array type formulas like this are not suited for that many inputs.  You will need vba and do the whole range once.  You are doing,assuming that you limited the range referenced to that of only the data, 4*16000*16000= 1,024,000,000 calculations, and if you used full column references then you are doing 4*1,048,576*16,000 =  67,108,864,000 calculations.  That will take a lot of time no matter the set up.  If you had said that you had 16,000 rows I would have suggested then to use vba and not formula.

Comment: being new to this, it didn't occur to me that the size of the data would be an issue. what would it take to use vba in this case and should I then modify the question?

Comment: no, do not modify the question.  It would open me up to down votes as my answer will no longer match.  Ask a new question, but beware, if you do not at least show an attempt to do the vba yourself, the question will be closed as too broad and most likely down voted.